# Linear embeddings are simplicial?

Tags: simplicial-complex

Let $K,L$ be finite simplicial complexes. Suppose there is a topological embedding $f: |K| \to |L|$ such that $f$ restricted to simplices of $K$ is linear (in particular $f(S)$ is completely inside a single simplex of $L$ for a simplex $S \in K$).

Is it always possible to find a subdivision of $L$, such that $f$ becomes simplicial? If not, what if $K$ and $L$ are PL-manifolds (with boundaries)? What is a good reference?

Comment: Why should it be true that $f(S)$ is contained in a single simplex?

Comment: What are you using as your reference for the definitions of simplicial complexes and their geometrical realisations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's always possible. Take a simplex $S$ of $K$ and subdivide the simplex of $L$ containing $f(S)$ so that $f(S)$ is a simplex of that subdivision (call the subdivision $L'$). For any other simplex $R$, $f(R)$ intersects the new simpleces of $L'$ linearly, and therefore $S'$ can be easily subdivided so that each simplex of the subdivision lies in a single simplex of $L'$ and we can continue by induction on $n$, where $n$ is the number of simpleces of $K$.